# How to compare 2 Data from UIImagePNGRepresentation?

Tags: compare, swift3

I had this in Swift 2.x

```
let data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)!
let data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
return data1.isEqualToData(data2)
```

But now Xcode 8 - Swift 3 tells me:

```
Value of type 'Data' has no member 'isEqualToData'
```

I also tried using `data1.isEqual(to: data2)` but it doesn't change much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is Swift, not objective C.  In Swift if a type conforms to the Equatable protocol (and Data is Equatable), then you use operator == to compare two instances and not .isEqaul:

```
return data1 == data2
```